LinearProgressWithLabel and CircularProgessWithLabel components not working/missing in MUI
I have a NextJS 12 application running Material UI 5.9.2, and for a reason I don't seem to have access to the LinearProgressWithLabel and CircularProgressWithLabel components. These two components are undefined when I try to import them (as in hovering them doesn't show the same information that other components do). For now, I'm trying to use just the former component.
Here are all relevant bits from my code:
import { Avatar, IconButton, LinearProgress, LinearProgressWithLabel, Menu, MenuItem, Step, StepLabel, Stepper, Tooltip } from '@mui/material';

<LinearProgress
  variant="determinate"
  value={stepperActiveStep ? (stepperActiveStep + 1) * 25 : 0}
/>
<LinearProgressWithLabel
  value={stepperActiveStep ? (stepperActiveStep + 1) * 25 : 0}
  color='brand'
  label={labels[stepperActiveStep]}
/>

package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.2",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.69",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.2",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.4.2",

Looking in node_modules/@mui/material, they're not even there. I see @mui/material/LinearProgress and @mui/material/CircularProgress though. I tried updating to 5.16.0, which is the latest v5, but they're still missing.

I can't find any issues online regarding them. My only option right now is to copy the source code and make my own components with them, but I'm wondering why they're not there when they're in the API docs and on GitHub.
Am I missing something here?

Ok, so upon closer inspection, even though they're documented in the MUI docs, it looks like they're both custom components MUI made themselves for demonstration purposes. They looked like native components at first because they were grouped with the rest of the examples, which are all native with just prop variations, but looking at the imports in the expanded code, LinearProgress and CircularProgress are just the base components used to make them. It could have been made a little clearer.
